# Prevent webstorm watcher from running on checkout new branch

Tags: webstorm

Add the moment my less and handlebar files get recompiled every time I check out another branch. Is there a way to run the watcher only when file was saved and not when it was changed in cause of checking out a branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible at the moment, unless you disable all file watchers before such VCS operations and then re-enable them again (which is not convenient: any of these steps you can easily forget next time).

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7912 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on progress.